# Number Base in Bash

Tags: bash, arithmetic-expressions

To force numbers to be interpreted in base10, you can prefix with 10#.  Specifically 10#08 and 10#09 will be interpreted as valid decimal numbers, and not invalid octal numbers. (I'm taking the output of `date +%S`)

However, it seems I then can't use the variable in comparisons:

```
x=10#08
y=10#20
echo $((x+y))           // (returns 28, as expected)

while [ $x -lt $y ]
do
  x=$((x++))
done
```

gives me the error

```
-bash: [: 10#08: integer expression expected
```

Is this a bug in bash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

bash's `[` builtin mostly emulates the old standard `[` command (aka `test`, and yes it's really a command), which doesn't know about these newfangled base marks. But bash's arithmetic expressions (`(( ))`) and conditional expressions (`[[ ]]`) do:

```
$ x=10#08
$ y=10#20
$ echo $((x+y))
28
$ [ $x -lt $y ] && echo yes
-bash: [: 10#08: integer expression expected
$ /bin/[ $x -lt $y ] && echo yes   # This uses external test cmd instead of builtin
[: 10#08: bad number
$ [[ $x -lt $y ]] && echo yes
yes
$ ((x<y)) && echo yes
yes
```

For purely arithmetic tests, `(( ))` is generally easiest to use. But both are bash extensions (i.e. not available in the brand-X shell), so be sure to start your script with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

How about `[ $(($x)) -lt $(($y)) ]` or `[[ $x -lt $y ]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug. The shell doesn't do arithmetic evaluation in conditional expressions. See the sections `Arithmetic Expansion` and `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` in `man bash` for details about when arithmetic evaluation is done.

Answer (score 0):

Just recently ran into this at work.  For the record, an assignment like `x=10#012` doesn't evaluate the math expression unless the shell parameter (variable) has the "integer" attribute.

```bash
$ printf "%d\n" 012
10                  # this is what we're trying to avoid in this case
$ printf "%d\n" 10#012
-bash: printf: 10#012: invalid number
10

$ x=10#012          # string in...
$ echo $x
10#012              # ...string out

$ echo $((x))       # do arithmetic evaluation
12
$ x=$((x))          # do arithmetic evaluation, assign its string value back
$ echo $x
12

# turning the integer attribute on with 'declare'/'local' forces
# arithmetic evaluation right away
$ declare -i y=10#012
$ echo y
12
```